# Can't get JSON from remote server with AngularJS $http.json/get

Tags: php, json, angularjs, jsonp

I'm having real trouble getting remote JSON file using AngularJS from a remote server, and even when I get it, I can't find a way of using the data.

Here is the angular code:

```
 var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.json('http://remotehost.mobi/temp.json').
        success(function(data){
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
    }).
        error(function(data, status ){
            console.log('error');
            console.log('status');

    });
}]);
```

Usually what I get are just all type of errors:

- when trying to get dynamic JSON from PHP script, I need to send a
  callback, which sometimes works, but the callback fires a function
  which is outside the scope, so it is irrelevant for my needs.
- when trying to load JSON from a .json file (like in the example)I get
  errors.
- when using $http.get I always get the cross domain security
  message.

I'm looking for a way to load json data from a remote server, generated dynamically by PHP,with angular JS controller and use it inside that controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I guess my issue was a bit different, that's why I post this solution.

Evantualy I have added the a new header to allow cross origin to my PHP that dynamically generates the JSON code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

This goes right before the function encode and returns the json. Another thing I have added is formatting the JSON before it sent back. I have found that sending the "raw" unformatted JSON back cause unexpected problems. Since PHP 5.4 you can add JSON_PRETTY_PRINT to the json_encode:

```
echo  json_encode($data_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

In the angular code, I checked many combinations, include @Endless suggestion to use corsproxy.com, but found that after these adjustments you can simply use `$http.get` .

Hope this helps if anyone encounter strange problems with this cross domain policy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the server to allow CORS (see [this](http://enable-cors.org/)) or use `$http.jsonp` and change the response to JSONP format (JSON body wrapped in a callback function call).

If you do not control the remote server, you can proxy the request through your own server so that it is no longer cross-domain.

Answer (score 1):

A example of a proxy that enables CORS is [corsproxy.com](http://www.corsproxy.com)

CORE is safer then jsonp cuz it has no way of executing javascript code. On the plus side you get more control over statechange/timeout/progress and abortion with CORS since its now ajax

The only risk now is do you trust corsproxy.com to read the data that are being passed through & the updown?

The only thing you have to do is replace `http://` with `http://www.corsproxy.com/` (don't think it works for https...)

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.json('http://www.corsproxy.com/kinneret.mobi/temp.json').
        success(function(data){
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status ){
            console.log('error');
            console.log('status');
        });
}]);
```